# Testand - Use of a C# DLL using a C# Wrapper using a C DLL

Tags: c#, c, dll, dllimport, teststand

There is a C-Funktion which I use as a DLL. The function is exported by

```
__declspec(dllexport) uint8_t *SomeFunction(uint8_t *a);
```

In the respective header file.

The wrapper imports the function with

```
[DllImport("SomeCFunction.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SomeFunction")]
private static extern IntPtr SomeFunction(Byte[] array1);
```

The wrapper has a method with which contains the call of that function

```
public unsafe Byte[] SomeFunction(Byte[] array1, Byte[] array2)
{
    IntPtr parray2 = CalculateKeyFromSeed(array1);

}
```

Now I get the Error when executing the step in TestStand:

> An exception occurred inside the call to .NET member
>   'SomeFunction': System.BadImageFormatException: Es wurde
>   versucht, eine Datei mit einem falschen Format zu laden. (Ausnahme von
>   HRESULT: 0x8007000B)    bei
>   SomeFunctionWrapperNameSpace.WrapperClass.SomeFunction(Byte[]
>   array1)    bei
>   WrapperNameSpace.WrapperClass.SomeFunction(Byte[]
>   array1, Byte[] array2) in
>   SomeFunctionWrapper.cs:Zeile
>   33.    bei SomeFunction(Byte[] array1, Byte[] array2) in
>   SomeFunction.cs:Zeile 39.

Some idea how I get TestStand accepting this DLL?

Comment: check the bitness, Is the dll 64bit? is the c# dll 64bit? what about the TestStand process?

Comment: You have been right! My TestStand Version is a 64bit one. In the properties of the C-DLL Project in VS2010 the Configuration Manager only allows 32bit xor 64bit. So I had to Change to 64bit. Another Problem was that my C# dll, which I used in TestStand was not set on "any CPU", but my Wrapper C# DLL was. FAZIT: set all C# Dll on "any CPU" and the C-Dll on what TestStand Version you have.

Comment: I'll put that as the answer then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BadImageFormat normally means there is a mismatch in the bitness of one of the parts.

These need to match, you have 3 parts to check

- Is the C dll 64-bit?
- Is the C# dll 64-bit? (AnyCPU should be OK here AFAIK)
- Is the TestStand process 64-bit?